# Capture and custom crop image with camera iOS

Tags: ios, image, camera, crop, resize-crop

I am using `UIImagePickerController` to capture the image. Now I want to crop the image. I am using `cameraOverlayView` method of `UIImagePicker` but it does not allow to move my cropping view. I want my cropping view should be moveable and resizable so that user can select image portion to use.
I am using the following code:

```
UIImagePickerController *cameraPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            cameraPicker.delegate = self;
            cameraPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            cameraPicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
            UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
            cameraPicker.cameraOverlayView =overlay;
            cameraPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
            [self presentViewController:cameraPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Can anyone suggest what can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void)pickphoto:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    imagePicker.navigationItem.title=@"Photo Albums";
    imagePicker.AllowsEditing = TRUE;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType;

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

    _imageV.image = image;
    _imageV.layer.borderColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    _imageV.layer.borderWidth=1.0;
    [imagePicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: @NishiBansal please set this  imagePicker.AllowsEditing = TRUE;

Comment: I have used that. But it does not allow my overlayView to move and resize to select region of image.

Comment: only replace cameraPicker.allowsEditing = NO; to  cameraPicker.allowsEditing = YES;

Comment: is your problem was solved? if yes than dont forget to up vote my answer.@NishiBansal

Comment: No. My problem is not yet solved. I want to resize my cropping window and movable too so that user can select which region he wants to crop.

Comment: @NishiBansal :D its not possible dear,its an iOS Feature for Selecting photo.we cant modified it.:)

Comment: Ok. I got that. Is this possible to resize image and as my image does not get crop from bottom.

Comment: https://github.com/myang-git/iOS-Image-Crop-View  -  -try this link its same as your problem

Comment: And it is Possible @NishiBansal

Comment: wel come :) @NishiBansal

Comment: how to crop face shape image objective c?